# Where can I download a large sample bibliography collection in BibTeX?

Tags: reference-managers

I'm developing an application that works with BibTeX files, and I'd like to test it with a large collection produced not by myself, to be sure that the application will handle it correctly and to assess its responsiveness (with large I mean at least a thousand of entries). But I cannot find any such collection available for download, even though there are many resources that provide bibliographies for queries online via html-pages. Does anyone know where I can download a large .bib file? (The topic of the collection is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 2):

For your purposes, I would highly recommend you to use [The Collection of
Computer Science Bibliographies](http://liinwww.ira.uka.de/bibliography) by *Alf-Christian Achilles*. This extensive collection contains **3M+** references on the various CS subjects (grouped in about 1500 collections) and, besides offering search and browse interfaces, allows one to *download the actual bibliographic data in BibTeX format* - just select a particular bibliography and you will see the links to the source files - uncompressed and/or zipped.

P.S. Don't forget to acknowledge the value of this resource to the maintainer of this meta-collection (a thank you note will do) and, perhaps, even attribute the source, if your software will be citable.

Comment: @jakebeal: Thank you! That's a long tail of the Web, I guess... :-)